# Web Components javascript ecmascript6

Tags: javascript, html, web, ecmascript-6, components

im working in aminiproyect. I have to modify an input with web components. I have modified the input (talking about style) but the behavior i cant do it. When i want to get the value that is writting in the input text it return me undefined, I dont know why... I fcan someone can help me or, can recommend me a book o a good PDF becauso this is new for me.

This is what i have: When i call the getValue funct, it return me unedefiend, i Dont know wy.

HTML:

```
    <input-mejorado></input-mejorado>
    <center><button id="verify">Verificar input</button></center>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    class inputVerification extends HTMLElement{

        constructor(){
            super();
            //this.addEventListener('blur',gettingValues);
        }

        connectedCallback(){ //cuando se mete en el dom, se inicia

            var shadowFuncion = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); 

                shadowFuncion.innerHTML =   
                `<div>
                <center> 
                <style>
                    input{
                        background-color: orange;
                        font-size: 150%;
                    }
                </style>

                <input type="text">
                <br>Hola, este es un webComponent modificado!<br>
                </center>
                </div>`
                ;

                this.addBlurListener();
        }

        addBlurListener() {
            this.addEventListener('blur', e=>{
                this.getValue();
                //alert("holas");
            });
        }

        getValue(){
            var valor = document.querySelector('input');
            if(valor==5){
                alert("Si agarra el numero");
            }else{
                alert("no hay vida");
            }
        }


    } //final


        window.customElements.define('input-mejorado',inputVerification);
        //document.createElement('input','input-mejorado');

</script>
```

Comment: Your `getValue` does not have a return statement. Just return the strings instead of alerting them? Not sure if that is what you wanted.

Comment: it return me 'null', that is what i want. I want to use that value that is written inside the input, but it return me null

Answer (score -1):

There are two major things wrong with your code.

1. You are calling the document querySelector method and not that of the shadow element.

   ```
   let valor = document.querySelector('input');
   ```

   This will retrieve the first input on the document, but does not search the shadow DOM of custom components and will not see the input you want.

   ```
   let valor = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
   ```

   [MDN shadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) This will get you the first input of your shadowRoot which in your case is the only one. Though if you switch to a closed mode element the method of accessing the shadowRoot is slightly different so this code won't work then.
2. You are not returning or even fully retrieving the value from the input you are getting.
   The modification I made above will still only get you the element, from which you still need to extract the actual value.

   ```
   let valor = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value;
   ```

   This will finally get the value out of the element you've selected, but unless you also return that value it will not be accessible from your getValue function.

Here is the getValue function with my suggested changes.

```
getValue(){
    const valor = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value;
    if (valor==5) {
        alert("Si agarra el numero");
    } else {
        alert("no hay vida");
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Aside from that you are using deprecated html in your shadowRoot. [center element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)